# mysqldump generating an empty file

Tags: php, windows, mysql

Im trying to use mysqldump like below:

```
mysqldump -hlocalhost -uadmin -padmin shop> D:\b2\shop3.sql
```

When i execute it in command prompt, the file shop3 is generated with all the tables from the shop database.
But, when I use it in my php file like below, it generates an empty file.

```
$cmd = 'mysqldump -hlocalhost -uadmin -padmin shop > D:\b2\shop3.sql';
        system($cmd);
```

Can anyone help me find my error please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysqldump may not be in the path, so try putting in an absolute `C:\....\mysqldump` in there. As well, add in a $return_val var to the call, so you can retrieve the exit value of the command. If mysqldump is failing for whatever reason, it will return a non-zero exit status and you can get that with `system($cmd, $return_val)`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have noticed on windows when making system calls, you need to point to the .bat file to run the command.